# Create List from comma seperated String making braced strings as one object

Tags: java, regex, string, list

I am using

```
List<String> items = Arrays.asList(stringValue.split("\\s*,\\s*"));
```

for converting comma separated string into list. 
But this is not working for one of the case.
I have input String as

```
john, M, 1001, 400000, 26, [101,
301, 201]
```

What I need is the last braced String [101, 301, 201] should be read as a single string.
Above code separate out these into separate String.
Please let me know how can we achieve this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
\[[^\]]*\]
```

You can simply grab the match instead of split.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/bW3aR1/15

Comment: I need all the strings in the inputString . Only requirement is the braced string should be read as a single string and not multiple string. So grabing will work. so grabbing will work , but i wll try if there is any way to convert string into list without grabbing each element

Comment: @alok https://regex101.com/r/bW3aR1/17 try this and grab the captures.group 1 and group 2 are your answers

Answer (score 0):

Use this to return all matches, and then trim all of those matches:

`\s*(?:\[[^\]]+\]|[^,]+)`

Answer (score 0):

If you know how many items your list will hold and the part in braces will always be at the end, you may also use the overridden split method

public String[] split(String regex, int limit)

There you can specify a limit of how many items there should be. So for your example it should work.